# Non singular matrices

Tags: matrices, inverse

> Assume matrices $A$, $I-A$, $I-A^{-1}$ are all non-singular. Show that $$(I-A)^{-1} + (I-A^{-1})^{-1} = I$$

Comment: Where's your work?

Answer (score 1):

$$\color{red}{(I-A)}\color{blue}{(I-A^{-1})}=I-A-A^{-1}+I = \color{red}{(I-A)}+\color{blue}{(I-A^{-1})}$$ Hence multiplying with the inverses:
first with $\color{red}{(I-A)^{-1}}$ on the left $$\color{blue}{I-A^{-1}}=I+\color{red}{(I-A)^{-1}}\color{blue}{(I-A^{-1})}$$
then with $\color{blue}{(I-A^{-1})^{-1}}$ on the right
$$I=\color{blue}{(I-A^{-1})^{-1}}+\color{red}{(I-A)^{-1}}$$

Comment: Sorry but this is hard to follow...

Comment: @zwim Hope it's more readable now.

Comment: It is thanks. I think a more straightforward way is to start from $(I-A^{-1})=-A^{-1}(I-A)$ then the sum factorize naturally (in particular we need only $A$ and $I-A$ invertible, the last one is automatic).

Comment: @zwim You should write it as an answer for reference.